# C++17 operator""s for string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17

Will C++17 contain a literal suffix for `const char*` to `std::string_view` conversion?

```
auto str = "asdf"s;
```

Will the type of `str` in the above statement be `std::string` or `std::string_view`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we're to believe [STL's comment](https://www.reddit.com/live/xx2k16ryk30m/updates/5d192906-a874-11e6-861f-0e9678d2dfa0), then yes, we'll have string view literal suffixes based on, I believe, [P0403R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0403r0.html).

If I understand things correctly `s` will stay a `std::string` literal suffix, while `std::string_view` will use `sv`.

```
cout << "Hello, string_view literals!"sv << endl;
cout << "Hello, string literals!"s << endl;
```

As of [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/889ee5a46000bb1f4635c84a347fe519b1676156#diff-dce54a16ad891d254c611a40d1a8564a) `sv` is in the Standard C++ draft.