# How to encode text using map?

Tags: c++

I am trying to encode hello world text as an example. But got a little lost with the implementation.

```
const map<string_view, int64_t> map_hello {
    {"h", 199 },{"e", 112 },{"l", 103 },{"o", 109 },{"w", 190 },{"r", 115 },{"d", 162 }
};
```

I got lost here I don’t know what to do next, how to compare the char and transfer the number to them.

```
string txt = "hello world";

for (auto i : txt) {


    cout << i << " result " << endl;

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you use `std::string_view` as key of map. Wouldn't be `char` appropriate? Btw. characters are rather limited and enumerable. A simple array instead of `std::map` would do as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encode"?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik get the word hello world in the form of numbers
each char will receive a unique code.

Comment: @Scheff In the future I want to use not one character, but 3 characters at once, so string.

Comment: OK. That could be worth to be mentioned in your question. Please, [edit] in case.

Comment: Define what you mean by "unique code", or "in the form of numbers of each char". Both of these are meaningless terms that require a precise, exact definition. There is no universal definition for what "unique code" or "form of numbers of each char" means. It means different things to different people. You should update your question and explain in more detail what exactly you're looking for, what you've tried, and what exactly doesn't work with your code.

Comment: it's better to use the `sv` suffix to get a string_view directly: `"h"sv`

Comment: @phuclv
`const map<string_view, int64_t> map_hello {
    {"h"sv, 199 },{"e"sv, 112 },{"l"sv, 103 },` so right?

Comment: @phuclv can i make a massive suffix to not write constantly sv?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667681/c17-operators-for-string-view
A person writes that sv is a standard, so it does not need to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to search for the corresponding value of your key with the `at()` method of `std::map`

```
int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string_view, int64_t> map_hello {
        {"hel", 199 },{"lo ", 112 },{"wor", 103 },{"ld!", 109 }
    };

    std::string txt = "hello world!";

    for(int i = 0; i < txt.size(); i += 3) {
        auto s1 = txt.substr(i, 3);
        std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
        auto s2 = map_hello.at(s1);
        std::cout << s2 << " result " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the reason why there is a string is that I can use specialized characters and 3-character words
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: @user Edited to use strings, also added a whitespace character

Comment: @user If you want 3 chararacter words you would have to change the map and the for loop

Comment: but how to change it is difficult?

Comment: your example almost suits me, probably the question about 3 characters is better to ask separately.

Comment: @user first you have to change the keys to strings with 3 characters. In the for loop you have to get substrings of size 3. I added a `!` because your string size isn't dividable by 3. You have to add an extra case, what to do, if the string isn't that size

Comment: it turns out I can encode either 1 character or 3 but not how not together right?

Comment: okay, then I'll ask a new question when I get to this, now your version suits me. thanks